# Is there an installer for the Windows version of the latest Resynthesizer plugin for Gimp?

Tags: software, gimp, windows, plugin

From here : http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219

> !!! The attached executables are Linux files. DO NOT download them for
>   Windows. Also do NOT download the Python scripts for Windows (they
>   won't work with the old resynthesizer.exe.) I have built the
>   resynthesizer and tested on Windows, but have not finished an
>   installer for Windows. If you are adept at building, download the
>   source and build Windows executables yourselves.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to build from source. Is there an already built of installer for Widnows around here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an official one. The [README](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer/blob/master/README) file for the new version (wow — about time!) says

> ## Building on other platforms
>
> (On the darkside OS, who hijacked a common word for fenestration)
>
> I use MinGW and MSYS. (Use mingw-get to download gnu build tools perl,
>   automake etc.) However it doesn't install plugins properly. You will
>   need to copy files to the proper Gimp plugin install directory,
>   typically from:
>
> c:\MSYS\1.0\usr\local\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins to:
>   c:\Doc...Settings\yourname.gimp-2.6\plug-ins

.. which suggests that there's no official binaries or installer, and that the programmer isn't particularly interested in that. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is a relatively — when compared to very complicated alternatives — system for building unix-like programs on Windows, or building them on Linux *to run on Windows*. And MSYS is a shell system for basically making the Windows command line more like Linux. Honestly, I'm not sure why one would do that instead of just running Linux.

In the comments to the registry.gimp.org page you link to, though, there's [this one](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219#comment-11413), where someone named "samj" has built binaries. If you trust running random programs from comments, you can download the binaries [from there](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25219#comment-11413). It seems reasonably trustworthy to me, really — the install instructions in the included `lisez-moi.txt` file look legit (and are basically understandable even if, like me, you don't speak French) — basically, copy all the files to `C:\Users\[username]\.gimp-2.6\plug-ins` and it should work. (You'll probably also need Python for Windows installed — that's a whole 'nuther thing.)

Or, you know, you could switch to Linux where this is all *just trivially easy*. :)